# Get a list of Web SQL databases

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I'm using WebSQL on my site (I'm trying to transition off of it). But, there are a bunch of different WebSQL databases on my site, each created with a different `openDatabase` database name.

My question is: is there a way to get a list of the WebSQL databases I've created in the user's browser?

Comment: You'll need to provide some context for concrete help. If you are the one creating them just keep a store of them in state?

Comment: The entire WebSQL API is deprecated and [slated to be removed from Chromium today](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/deprecating-web-sql/). Also the first line in the [API section of the standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#sql) reads *'There is no way to enumerate or delete the databases available for an origin from this API.'*

Comment: We're participating in the deprecation trial. https://developer.chrome.com/blog/deprecating-web-sql/

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

@pilchard posted the right answer in a comment:

> The first line in the [API section of the standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#sql) reads 'There is no way to enumerate or delete the databases available for an origin from this API.'